# Алгоритм быстрого объединения - объяснение циклов

Tags: c++, циклы

Разъясните, пожалуйста, такие циклы,нигде такое не встречал:

```
for (i = p;i != id[i];i = id[i]);
for (j = q;j != id[j];j = id[j]);
```

Этот пример из Сейджвик Роберт-Алгоритмы на С++. Решение связности методом быстрого объединения.

Comment: А в чем проблема? Обычные циклы... Инициализация переменной; условие продолжение цикла; оператор для каждой итерации.

Comment: я такое часто видел когда несколько списков в один массив ложили. В поле id[i] хранится следующий (а обычно предыдущий) элемент для списка содержащего i

Comment: Мне кажется, что человеку просто не ясна последовательность выполнения действий (и то какие именно действия могут находиться в нем) и проверок в `for`, иначе бы он такой вопрос не задавал.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Я так понял, что ваша проблема, как минимум, частично заключается в недопонимании логики работы `for`, поэтому стоит начать именно с этого.

Согласно [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b80153d8.aspx):

```
for (init-expression; cond-expression; loop-expression)
   statement;
```

1. `init-expression` выполняется только один раз перед любым другим элементом оператора `for`, а затем управление передается `cond-expression`
2. `cond-expression` выполняется перед выполнением каждой итерации `statement`, включая первую итерацию. `statement` выполняется только в том случае, если `cond-expression` имеет значение `true` (по факту, отличное от `0` значение)
3. `loop-expression` выполняется в конце каждой итерации `statement`. После выполнения `loop-expression` производится вычисление `cond-expression`

Таким образом, сильно жестких ограничений на элементы `for` не накладывается (да и стоит заметить, что они вообще могут отсутствовать, например, бесконечный цикл: `for (;true;)` или даже так `for (;;)`)

---

Касательно вашего примера: `for (i = p; i != id[i]; i = id[i]);`

Начиная с индекса `p` перед входом в тело самого `for` (`statement`) идет проверка на факт неравенства индекса и элемента массива по этому индексу (`i != id[i]`), в случае успеха выполняется тело цикла (`statement`). Затем меняется индекс на элемент массива по этому индексу (`i = id[i]`) и опять выполняется проверка `i != id[i]` и так далее.

Как вам подсказывают в комментарии, такое часто применяется, когда несколько списков кладут в один массив. В таком случае, элемент c индексом `i` массива `id` (`id[i]`) хранит следующий/предыдущий элемент для списка содержащего `i`.

Причем, судя по всему, в конце каждого такого "списка", хранящегося в этом массиве, должен находиться элемент, который дублирует начальный, иначе же условие завершения цикла недостижимо и рано или поздно произойдет просто выход за границы массива (либо у вас там идет работа с нестандартными списками с переопределенным поведением `operator[]` или что-то в этом духе).